# TodoList sample Bing Maps service returns error with status blank

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I am working thru the sample todolist application for the Cordova SDK.

the url is here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn832630.aspx

I set up a key on the BING Maps website.  I can access the location service sending latitude and longitude thru a standard web browser, pasting in the URL with my key.

However the angular call always fails.  What is worse is the error is always blank.  no status code no error message.  Was thinking it must be CORS.

I have run through the sample and downloaded the code sample and both have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone going thru the sample.  I have realised today that Angular is evil.  They say it is nicely testable javascript with dependancy injection, however it doesn't seem to be too interested in telling you what the error is when you have one, it just fails.  Great and noble programming ideas, but without an error message it isn't much good.

Anyhow the fix is that Angular is very strict about json code so the line in services.js for the Bings Maps Service method getAddressFromPosition

it used to work with .get() but this was probably an old version of Angular when the demo was written.  I tried using 1.2 but the Ripple emulator didn't like references to browser specific code.  So I used the latest 1.3.13 I believe.

This is where to access the Bing location service with the Cordova geolocation coordinates returns Json, but Angular wants them wrapped in JSONP.  searching the increasing fragmented web it appeared the error might be CORS no, so a many different people had their JSONP calls in controllers, modules, services, some using $http others $resources.  Finally using bits and pieces I got JSONP to work with $resources and to plug it into the $promise the call from the controller requires.  I used a static Url with Coordinates I knew worked, so you will have to use the :param angular notation to put those back in.  Hope it helps someone.

So change to:

```
getAddressFromPosition: function (position) {
  var resource = $resource(url, {}, {
    jsonp_query: {
        method: 'JSONP'
    }
  });
  return resource.jsonp_query().$promise.then(function (response) {
    return response.resourceSets[0].resources[0].address.formattedAddress;
  }, function (error) {
    return position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude
  });
```

edit:

I put the above in and it worked.  However the problem was for some reason, perhaps thru debugging, another instance of the app was deployed on another port in ripple.  This then change the app to run on this new port.  The initial port was 4400.  The problem is that and $http or $resource calls in angular have to go thru this emulator, and the emulator was seeing this as cross domain, unless it is configured to the same port the app is running under.

so Url:
http://localhost:4409/index.html?enableripple=cordova-3.0.0-iPhone5

then in the Settings Div dropdown on the right side, the Proxy Port must also be set to 4409 or else the browser will complain that the $http request is cross-domain, before the emulator actually executes it to query Azure mobile service or Bing maps.

So this was very frustrating.  However VS Cordova has definately reduced the amount of bits you have to configure to make hybrid mobile apps, there are still little glitches like this which can trip you up.  I assumed it was something with angular, because there was no error messages, but in Chrome in the Dev Tools console that was where the error was, and after some googling it was plain that it was the ripple emulator running on a different port than its proxy was not allowing the call to be forwarded on due to Access-Control-Allow not being set.